# Prevent external script from loading using Burp

Tags: javascript, http-proxy, burp-suite

I am using free edition of Burp Suite to analyze some requests. Suppose, website is `https://www.example.com`.

Now, there is a javascript file in `https://www.example.com/templates/scripts/xyz.js`. I want to prevent this file from loading while intercepting the requests.

Is there any way in Burp, so that I can drop this resource file?

Comment: Intercept the server response and remove the contents of the JavaScript file from the response.

Comment: Can't you just drop the request for the file? Click 'Drop' instead of 'Forward'?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a "match and replace" rule. Under `Proxy > Options > Match and Replace`, click the `Add` button, and fill in the necessary fields so that if the request body contains that URL, Burp will remove it from the request.

[image]

[image]

You could also remove all JavaScript resources by ticking the `Remove all JavaScript` field under `Response Modification`.

[image]